# XML how do I select and display a certain element?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need my XML to cycle through the list of elements, and only display the one that has 'Web Development' inside of it. I've tried countless solutions, but nothing seems to provide the desired output.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<assignment>
    <workhistory>
        <workplace>
            <jobinfo>
                <joblength>March - February</joblength>
                <jobrole>Librarian</jobrole>
            </jobinfo>  
        </workplace>

        <workplace>
            <jobinfo>
                <joblength>April - July</joblength>
                <jobrole>Web Development</jobrole>
            </jobinfo>  
        </workplace>
    </workhistory>
</assignment>
```

XSL Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="assignment"> 
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="workhistory/workplace/jobinfo/jobrole"/> 
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

I know that this prints all of the 'jobrole' elements and I understand why, I just can't work out how to output what I want it to. 
Note: I'm using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Add a predicate `<xsl:apply-templates select="workhistory/workplace/jobinfo/jobrole[. = 'Web Development']"/>`.

Comment: Ah, this works perfectly. I had tried something similar but using somewhat different syntax (obviously that didn't work). Would you be able to explain how this works to me? Just for peace of mind.

Comment: Well XSLT works together with XPath and the XPath language allows you to add predicates in square brackets to filter the set of nodes an expression selects. Read http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ for details of the language. Or start with an XPath tutorial like http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html if you are new to it.